# Add or remove EditText

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I hope you can help me with my question, I would like to know if there is any library or how to make a list where you can add or remove from the same list EditText

[In the image, the example of the question I am asking is clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5ouH.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for telephones

https://github.com/lamudi-gmbh/android-phone-field

[image]